# Dashed bibliography with alphabetic style

Tags: biblatex

I recently switched a document where the bibliography was generated with `bibtex` using the *amsalpha* bibstyle to `biblatex`. The *alphabetic* style looks nice enough, but I am missing the dashes that *amsalpha* generated if an author had multiple entries. `biblatex`es documentation states that the `dashed` option is only available for *authoryear* and some other style, but not for *alphabetic*. Why is that, and how do I get the dashes back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative solution is to use the `ieee-alphabetic` style, provided by the [`biblatex-ieee`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ieee) bundle. I'm not sure yet that there isn't any critical difference with the `alphabetic` style, but it has the essentials at least: alphabetic labels and grouping of similar authors with dashes.

```
\usepackage[style=ieee-alphabetic]{biblatex}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you! Looks OK. For the record: This style is loaded with `\usepackage[style=ieee-alphabetic]{biblatex}`. Strangely enough, `\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}` does not work, maybe I should update TeXlive.

Comment: Oh, right, wanted to add it, forgot for whatever reason. Thanks for reminding me! Btw, if `ieee-alphabetic` works, `ieee` should as well, as they're part of the same package! What's the error, exactly?

Comment: It just does not compile with `ieee`, but since I don't need it right now, I don't care too much. Thanks again!

Comment: Other things I noticed about the `ieee` style: It is only localized for the english language, and I don't like how URLs are formatted. The latter can be changed by adding `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{url = URL\addspace ,}` in the preamble.

Comment: The documentation of the `biblatex-ieee` package is very short (1 page of instructions and 3 pages of examples), but it does address the url issue. About localization, I tested it on a french document of mine and it seems perfectly localized. What strings are you missing?

Comment: @T.Verron: One difference with `amsalpha` is that it abbreviates given names of authors even if that isn't what one wants. Do you know a workaround?

Comment: @jdc that's what the `giveninits` option is for, no?

Answer (score 8):

Based on the (now deleted) idea of T.Verron you can use a bibstyle which supports the dash-option. Instead of the predefined bibliography environment of `authortitle` you can use the default of `alphabetic`. All needed options to provide the labels are down by the style `alphabetic`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,bibstyle=authortitle]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{default}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelalpha}%
        \printfield{extraalpha}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelalphawidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\defbibenvironment{shorthands}
  {\list
     {\printfield[shorthandwidth]{shorthand}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\shorthandwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Text 
\cite{knuth:ct,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d,knuth:ct:e}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To setup the format of the dash you can define the dash as follows:

```
\renewcommand*{\bibnamedash}{\mbox{\textemdash\space}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But somehow … I have a feeling that there exists a more elegant solution – or that there should exist one, at least.

Comment: For whatever reason, the space after the dash seems far too large.

Comment: @PercivalUlysses: The more elegant solution would be the implementation of the feature in the style `alphabetic` itself.

Comment: "[…] *implementation of the feature in the style alphabetic itself*" I agree.

Comment: traditionally, the length of the dash is 3 ems.  that can be decided at the (la)tex level, which is why `amsalpha.bst` (and other ams biblio processors) encode the duplication as `\bysame`.