# Is there already an amsalpha.bbx?

Tags: biblatex, amsart

I searched but did not find one.

If it does not yet exist, is there a project on biblatex style files for AMS journals?

Comment: You might try http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101459/15925

Comment: Perhaps make clear if you are interested for 'personal' use or journal submission. The latter is in general not well supported with `biblatex` at the moment and Barbara's answer makes clear simply not accepted by the AMS.

Comment: okok ... then I'll just keep a personal cfg ... for fun.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

AMS publications do not support `biblatex`.

Only BibTeX and `amsrefs` are accepted.

There is no plan to support `biblatex`.

**Edit:**
The AMS, in order to satisfy demands from journal aggregators and on-line bibliographic
services, now converts all bibliographies for journals and books that are being published
in "dual form" (both in print and electronically) to a uniform `amsrefs` style, with the
"canonical" reference (if one exists) drawn from MathSciNet, replacing what the author
has submitted.  As this is done automatically, with as little manual intervention as
possible, the permissible variation in style of entries is limited to what is already
"known".

Comment: note uppercasing.  this is *official*.

Comment: If a `biblatex` style appeared based on AMS guidelines, maybe the Society might consider it. Probably it couldn't contain `ams` in its name, at least unless and until the Society endorses it.

Comment: sorry, @egreg.  the ams policy is more complicated than that.  i'm at this very moment entombing it in an updated author handbook.  i'll add the details to my answer.