# Any amsalpha-like style in Biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, amsrefs

Did anyone know is there a way to set style for biblatex? I would like a way to backref the cited page with linkedin hyperref, it seems that the Biblatex can do this, but the style is quite ugly!!! I'd like a style as amsalpha, any ideas?

## Some examples:

### My original tex source

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{backref}
\usepackage[backref]{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book {jost1995riemannian,
    AUTHOR = {Jost, J{\"u}rgen},
     TITLE = {Riemannian geometry and geometric analysis},
    SERIES = {Universitext},
   EDITION = {Sixth},
 PUBLISHER = {Springer},
   ADDRESS = {Heidelberg},
      YEAR = {2011},
     PAGES = {xiv+611},
      ISBN = {978-3-642-21297-0},
   MRCLASS = {53Cxx (35R01 53-02 57R58 58E05 58E20 58J05)},
  MRNUMBER = {2829653},
MRREVIEWER = {Fr{\'e}d{\'e}ric Robert},
       DOI = {10.1007/978-3-642-21298-7},
       URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-21298-7},
}
@book {freed1984instantons,
    AUTHOR = {Freed, Daniel S. and Uhlenbeck, Karen K.},
     TITLE = {Instantons and four-manifolds},
    SERIES = {Mathematical Sciences Research Institute Publications},
    VOLUME = {1},
   EDITION = {Second},
 PUBLISHER = {Springer-Verlag},
   ADDRESS = {New York},
      YEAR = {1991},
     PAGES = {xxii+194},
      ISBN = {0-387-97377-X},
   MRCLASS = {57R55 (57M40 57N05 57R57 57R60 58D27 58G10)},
  MRNUMBER = {1081321 (91i:57019)},
       DOI = {10.1007/978-1-4613-9703-8},
       URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4613-9703-8},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\cite{jost1995riemannian,freed1984instantons}
\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

### The one for Biblatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backref=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book {jost1995riemannian,
    AUTHOR = {Jost, J{\"u}rgen},
     TITLE = {Riemannian geometry and geometric analysis},
    SERIES = {Universitext},
   EDITION = {Sixth},
 PUBLISHER = {Springer},
   ADDRESS = {Heidelberg},
      YEAR = {2011},
     PAGES = {xiv+611},
      ISBN = {978-3-642-21297-0},
   MRCLASS = {53Cxx (35R01 53-02 57R58 58E05 58E20 58J05)},
  MRNUMBER = {2829653},
MRREVIEWER = {Fr{\'e}d{\'e}ric Robert},
       DOI = {10.1007/978-3-642-21298-7},
       URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-21298-7},
}
@book {freed1984instantons,
    AUTHOR = {Freed, Daniel S. and Uhlenbeck, Karen K.},
     TITLE = {Instantons and four-manifolds},
    SERIES = {Mathematical Sciences Research Institute Publications},
    VOLUME = {1},
   EDITION = {Second},
 PUBLISHER = {Springer-Verlag},
   ADDRESS = {New York},
      YEAR = {1991},
     PAGES = {xxii+194},
      ISBN = {0-387-97377-X},
   MRCLASS = {57R55 (57M40 57N05 57R57 57R60 58D27 58G10)},
  MRNUMBER = {1081321 (91i:57019)},
       DOI = {10.1007/978-1-4613-9703-8},
       URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4613-9703-8},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{jost1995riemannian,freed1984instantons}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this question help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101459/dashed-bibliography-with-alphabetic-style

Comment: @egreg it helps a litter, in fact I want the later example with biblatex shall looks almost the same as the first one, in addtion the page number in the end of bibitem shall be linked back to the page.

Answer (score 1):

A not so perfect solution is:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[backref=true,
    backend=bibtex,% or biber
    style=alphabetic,
    citestyle=authoryear,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    natbib=true,
    doi=false,
    isbn=false,
    url=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
%  backrefpage = {page},% originally "cited on page"
%  backrefpages = {pages},% originally "cited on pages"
%}
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\parentexttrack}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \blx@bibopenparen#1\blx@bibcloseparen
  \endgroup}

\AtEveryCite{%
  \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
  \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}

\makeatother
\renewcommand{\cite}{\parencite}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book {jost1995riemannian,
    AUTHOR = {Jost, J{\"u}rgen},
     TITLE = {Riemannian geometry and geometric analysis},
    SERIES = {Universitext},
   EDITION = {Sixth},
 PUBLISHER = {Springer},
   ADDRESS = {Heidelberg},
      YEAR = {2011},
     PAGES = {xiv+611},
      ISBN = {978-3-642-21297-0},
   MRCLASS = {53Cxx (35R01 53-02 57R58 58E05 58E20 58J05)},
  MRNUMBER = {2829653},
MRREVIEWER = {Fr{\'e}d{\'e}ric Robert},
       DOI = {10.1007/978-3-642-21298-7},
       URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-21298-7},
}
@book {freed1984instantons,
    AUTHOR = {Freed, Daniel S. and Uhlenbeck, Karen K.},
     TITLE = {Instantons and four-manifolds},
    SERIES = {Mathematical Sciences Research Institute Publications},
    VOLUME = {1},
   EDITION = {Second},
 PUBLISHER = {Springer-Verlag},
   ADDRESS = {New York},
      YEAR = {1991},
     PAGES = {xxii+194},
      ISBN = {0-387-97377-X},
   MRCLASS = {57R55 (57M40 57N05 57R57 57R60 58D27 58G10)},
  MRNUMBER = {1081321 (91i:57019)},
       DOI = {10.1007/978-1-4613-9703-8},
       URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4613-9703-8},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{jost1995riemannian,freed1984instantons}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I also found a perfect one:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}
\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
    \ifcase #1
        No cited.
    \or
        page #2.
    \else
        pages #2.
    \fi
}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book {jost1995riemannian,
    AUTHOR = {Jost, J{\"u}rgen},
     TITLE = {Riemannian geometry and geometric analysis},
    SERIES = {Universitext},
   EDITION = {Sixth},
 PUBLISHER = {Springer},
   ADDRESS = {Heidelberg},
      YEAR = {2011},
     PAGES = {xiv+611},
      ISBN = {978-3-642-21297-0},
   MRCLASS = {53Cxx (35R01 53-02 57R58 58E05 58E20 58J05)},
  MRNUMBER = {2829653},
MRREVIEWER = {Fr{\'e}d{\'e}ric Robert},
       DOI = {10.1007/978-3-642-21298-7},
       URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-21298-7},
}
@book {freed1984instantons,
    AUTHOR = {Freed, Daniel S. and Uhlenbeck, Karen K.},
     TITLE = {Instantons and four-manifolds},
    SERIES = {Mathematical Sciences Research Institute Publications},
    VOLUME = {1},
   EDITION = {Second},
 PUBLISHER = {Springer-Verlag},
   ADDRESS = {New York},
      YEAR = {1991},
     PAGES = {xxii+194},
      ISBN = {0-387-97377-X},
   MRCLASS = {57R55 (57M40 57N05 57R57 57R60 58D27 58G10)},
  MRNUMBER = {1081321 (91i:57019)},
       DOI = {10.1007/978-1-4613-9703-8},
       URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4613-9703-8},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{jost1995riemannian,freed1984instantons}
\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\end{document}
```