# References & Bibliography in Beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibliographies, citing, footnotes

I am trying to implement full citations in footnotes in Beamer as I found on the latex wikibooks https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Presentations, and the reference style found at [bibliography in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30423/bibliography-in-beamer). I can't seem to make it work, am I missing something? Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[10pt,handout,english]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib2.bib}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

 \frametitle{Title}
 A reference~\footfullcite{Amin}, with ref_bib an item of the .bib file.

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{References}
        \bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
        \bibliography{bib2.bib}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you load the `biblatex` package, you should replace `\bibliography{bib2.bib}` by `\printbibliography` and remove `\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}`, the style is defined as optional argument during package loading, `numeric-comp` in your example. Please also note that you have to use biber instead of bibtex with the code your show.

In case you prefer a style imitating the `amsalpha` style, see [Any amsalpha-like style in Biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209747/any-amsalpha-like-style-in-biblatex)

```
\documentclass[10pt,handout,english]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,sorting=none]{biblatex}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib2.bib}
@book{knuth,
  author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title        = {The {\TeX} book},
  date         = 1984,
  maintitle    = {Computers \& Typesetting},
  volume       = {A},
  publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
  location     = {Reading, Mass.},
  langid       = {english},
  langidopts   = {variant=american},
  sortyear     = {1984-1},
  sorttitle    = {Computers & Typesetting A},
  indexsorttitle= {The TeXbook},
  indextitle   = {\protect\TeX book, The},
  shorttitle   = {\TeX book}
}

@article{einstein,
    author = {Einstein, A.},
    title = {Die Grundlage der allgemeinen Relativitätstheorie},
    journal = {Annalen der Physik},
    volume = {354},
    number = {7},
    doi = {10.1002/andp.19163540702},
    pages = {769--822},
    year = {1916}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{bib2.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

 \frametitle{Title}
 A reference\footfullcite{knuth}, with refbib an item of the .bib file.

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{References}
%        \bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\printbibliography
%        \bibliography{bib2.bib}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I tried and it did not work. So I tried to just copy/paste your MWE in a new .tex file and ran it to see it still does not work. I'm uploading the result it prints here if I can.

Comment: @OlivierMassicot Did you run biber?

Comment: Excuse me, I don't know biber. I'm working on TeXshop, the only bibliography tool I see is BibTeX. I tried to run it but gives me error and does not seem to work. I think it may be it.

Comment: @OlivierMassicot see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323515/how-do-i-run-biber-on-texshop and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations you need biber not bibtex

Comment: Oh I see, I think it is working now. I'll give it some more tries then I'll check your answer as correct! Thank you!

Comment: @OlivierMassicot You're welcome!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86961/discussion-between-olivier-massicot-and-samcarter).

Comment: @OlivierMassicot See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232293/36296 how to remove some fields