# References & Bibliography in Beamer with different colors

Tags: beamer, bibtex, color

How can I change the color of `\footfullcite` in beamer? The example citation below is blue and black but I need everything in white (because I have a black background).

For the minimal example I took the solution of the question [References & Bibliography in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464434/references-bibliography-in-beamer). However, biber did't worked for my, I used bibtex. But this is not the question.

Because of the fact that I use a black background for my presentation and a white one for the handout, I need different colors for the citation itself.

The following example can be compiled with pdflatex, bibtex, 2x pdflatex

```
\documentclass[10pt,handout,english]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib2.bib}
@book{knuth,
  author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title        = {The {\TeX} book},
  date         = 1984,
  maintitle    = {Computers \& Typesetting},
  volume       = {A},
  publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
  location     = {Reading, Mass.},
  langid       = {english},
  langidopts   = {variant=american},
  sortyear     = {1984-1},
  sorttitle    = {Computers & Typesetting A},
  indexsorttitle= {The TeXbook},
  indextitle   = {\protect\TeX book, The},
  shorttitle   = {\TeX book}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{bib2.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

 \frametitle{Title}
 A reference\footfullcite{knuth}, with refbib an item of the .bib file.

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{References}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using code slightly adapted from the duplicate: `\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry author}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry title}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry note}{fg=white}`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That was what I'm looking for.